# What is the opposite of someone who has been sheltered?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I am looking for a word to describe a teenager as someone who is "not sheltered." Someone who has been exposed to many different people, communities and ways of thinking. Worldly seems too broad of a word as it should relate to experiences within his community. I'm also looking for a word that more closely relates to how he was raised and what he was allowed to have access too. If a child is not sheltered they are what?

Comment: The homeless, do you mean?

Comment: S/he has had A WIDE EXPOSURE to the world and its many people-groups, cultures and worldviews, thanks to his/her parents and the way they reared him.

Comment: What about a gypsy? Drifter?

Comment: A seasoned traveler?

Comment: The term "sophisticated" comes to mind: "altered by education, experience, etc., so as to be worldly-wise" From: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sophisticated

Comment: That child could be anything from *well-adjusted* to *well-socialized* to *street-wise* to *psychologically damaged*

Comment: Often such a person is a "free spirit".

Answer (score 5):

Actually *street-smart* or *streetwise* makes a very good opposite to *sheltered*. Here is the entry in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* for *streetwise*:

> **streetwise** *adj* (1965): possessing the skills and attitudes necessary to survive in a difficult or dangerous situation or environment

Given how recently *streetwise* and *street-smart* (which MW says dates to 1974) arose, they may have been coined in direct contrast to *sheltered*. Google Books finds instances of "sheltered life" in its modern sense from at least as long ago as 1854, in [*Youthful Pilgrims; or, Memorials of Young Persons of the Society of Friends*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sFEBAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA79&dq=%22sheltered+life%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid1YOz6srKAhVBzWMKHaJACX44ChDoAQgtMAI#v=onepage&q=%22sheltered%20life%22&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience as one who was ostensibly "sheltered," the opposite was usually **socialized**:

> to fit or train for a social environment ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/socialized))

It's related to *socialization*, as in:

> the process in which people, especially children, learn to behave in a way that is accepted by society ([MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/socialization))

Answer (score 0):

[exposed](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/exposed):

> without shelter from the elements

(Collins Online Dictionary)